# Cor do menu Collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

Tenho um problema com o menu bootstrap quando ele está "colapsado". Quando o tamanho da tela é por exemplo de um mobile, ele fica com aquele botão para clicar e abrir o menu. O problema é que se eu deixo o tag `<nav>` com a class `navbar-default` quando o menu está aberto normalmente (em um desktop ou algo grande) ele fica com a cor da classe `navbar-default`. Se eu retiro a classe `navbar-default` quando o monitor do usuário é menor, então não aparece o botão, pois ele não tem um background para aparecer.

Eu gostaria que a classe `navbar-default` só fosse ativa (com o background) se o menu for "colapsado". Se estiver do tamanho normal, então não deixa estilizado. Um exemplo é o site www.iped.com.br . Quando está em desktop (dimensão) então ele não aparece o menu collapsado (até ai tudo bem), quando deixamos o navegador em uma dimensão menor, então aparece o menu collapsado com estilo (background cinza claro), gostaria de fazer o mesmo. Meu código:

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="menu">

              <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                  </button>
                </div>

                <div id="menu-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sobre nós</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Localização & Contato</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Orçamento</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

              </nav>

            </div>
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Você quer que o nav-default apareça apenas em telas menores?

Comment: Sim... pois se estão em dimensões maiores (desktops, etc.) ele estiliza o meu menu, sendo que não é preciso. Quando for em telas menores quero que fique com o nav-default ai sim pode estilizar, pois vai estar com aquele botão para abrir o menu

Comment: olhe as 2 imagens http://img.gforum.tv/img/7c1472a21254c4f50c2ed85854c376219dca1688.png e http://img.gforum.tv/img/e4f1a8139909e54f2b23086464f434620d20846d.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para funcionar que nem o site da ipded é só colocar as classes `.hidden-xs` e `.hidden-sm` na tag nav. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-print

Dessa forma:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default hidden-xs hidden-sm">
```

Comment: É quase isso que preciso, só que o seguinte, se a dimensão for pequena com seu código ele esconde o "botão" para abrir o menu. O que quero, é que só estilize o menu quando for para dimensão menor. Quando tiver na dimensão normal (desktops) ele não estilize o menu

Comment: olhe as 2 imagens http://img.gforum.tv/img/7c1472a21254c4f50c2ed85854c376219dca1688.png e http://img.gforum.tv/img/e4f1a8139909e54f2b23086464f434620d20846d.png

Comment: Entendi, só não sei como o bootstrap faz por "detrás dos panos" para fazer algumas classes só terem efeito de acordo com a resolução do dispositivo. Mas é bem curioso.

Comment: E se colocar o navbar-default na div navbar-header ?

Comment: kkkkk, deu certo! navbar-default na "navbar-header" ... Obrigado Sertage!!